# Object instance creation with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I have written three lines of codes with Python 3.6, as follows,

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
```

what I'm expecting is that there should be just one instance of fig and ax.
but when I attempt to show the image, using plt.show(), it gives me three blank figures.

So why three instances of fig have been created, isn't the instance created in last line overriding the previously two?

Comment: forget to add, that i'm using the module of matplotlib

Comment: You create three instances, but only the last is available under the variable name.

Comment: Hi, then why three blank figures are shown using plt.show()? I thought only the last instance is shown.

Comment: You create 3 figures. Those three are shown.